# Regex to extract strings within delimiter

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to extract string occurences within delimiters (parentheses in this case) but not the ones which are within quotes (single or double). Here is what I have tried - this regex fetches all occurences within parentheses, also the ones which are within quotes (I don't want the ones within quotes)

```
public class RegexMain {
    static final String PATTERN = "\\(([^)]+)\\)";
    static final Pattern CONTENT = Pattern.compile(PATTERN);
    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String testString = "Rhyme (Jack) and (Jill) went up the hill on \"(Peter's)\" request.";
        Matcher match = CONTENT.matcher(testString);
        while(match.find()) {
            System.out.println(match.group()); // prints Jack, Jill and Peter's
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If I were you I would first replace quoted parts by an empty string then look for the matched groups. Isn't that an option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try

```
public class RegexMain {
    static final String PATTERN = "\\(([^)]+)\\)|\"[^\"]*\"";
    static final Pattern CONTENT = Pattern.compile(PATTERN);
    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String testString = "Rhyme (Jack) and (Jill) went up the hill on \"(Peter's)\" request.";
        Matcher match = CONTENT.matcher(testString);
        while(match.find()) {
            if(match.group(1) != null) {
                System.out.println(match.group(1)); // prints Jack, Jill
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This pattern will match quoted strings as well as parenthesized ones but only the parenthesized ones will put something in `group(1)`.  Since `+` and `*` are greedy in regular expressions it will prefer to match `"(Peter's)"` over `(Peter's)`.

Comment: +1, I modified the regex to "\\(([^)]+)\\)|\"[^\"]*\"|'[^']*'" which then also includes the check for strings in single quotes. Also, as an alternative, we could still work with match.group(0) (working on only the strings starting with parentheses). However, I would wait before accepting this answer as I believe there should be a way to do it directly with regex (without having to deal with group(0) and group(1) - I just don't know how.

Answer (score 1):

This is a case where you can make elegant use of look-behind and look-ahead operators to achieve what you want. Here is a solution in Python (I always use it for trying out stuff quickly on the command line), but the regular expression should be the same in Java code.

This regex matches content that is preceded by an opening parenthesis using positive look-behind and succeeded by a closing parenthesis using positive look-ahead. But it avoids these matches when the opening parenthesis is preceded by a single or double quote using negative look-behind and when the closing parenthesis is succeeded by a single or double quote using negative look-ahead.

```
In [1]: import re

In [2]: s = "Rhyme (Jack) and (Jill) went up the hill on \"(Peter's)\" request."

In [3]: re.findall(r"""
   ...:     (?<=               # start of positive look-behind
   ...:         (?<!           # start of negative look-behind
   ...:             [\"\']     # avoids matching opening parenthesis preceded by single or double quote
   ...:         )              # end of negative look-behind
   ...:         \(             # matches opening parenthesis
   ...:     )                  # end of positive look-behind
   ...:     \w+ (?: \'\w* )?   # matches whatever your content looks like (configure this yourself)             
   ...:     (?=                # start of positive look-ahead
   ...:         \)             # matches closing parenthesis 
   ...:         (?!            # start of negative look-ahead
   ...:             [\"\']     # avoids matching closing parenthesis succeeded by single or double quote
   ...:         )              # end of negative look-ahead  
   ...:     )                  # end of positive look-ahead
   ...:     """, 
   ...:     s, 
   ...:     flags=re.X)
Out[3]: ['Jack', 'Jill']
```

Comment: unfortunately I don't understand the python construct (re.findall) too well and couldn't try it with java.

Comment: @Scorpion As you can see in my example, [`re.findall()`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/re.html#re.findall) returns all non-overlapping occurrences of a pattern in a string. Your Java code basically achieves the same using [`Matcher.find()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29) in a `while` loop. I'm not a Java expert, but probably you just have to add all matches to a list or sth. Depends on what you want to do with the matches.

Comment: @Scorpion There were some mistakes in my solution. Please take a look at the corrected version. Now it works as you expect it.

Comment: +1, really appreciate your looking into it; however it still doesn't work for the complete use case example if the text withing the quotes was \" Mr. (Peter's) \" text preceding or succeeding parentheses - but I guess this can be customized to fix the behavior. Java regex is ("(?<=(?<![\"'])\\()\\w+(?:'\\w* )?(?=\\)(?![\"']))")

Comment: @Scorpion You did not say in your question that there can be text between a quote and a parenthesis. In the future, please be more specific about your use cases from the beginning. But I'm sure you know now how to adjust the regex to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** This is not the final response because I'm not familiar with JAVA but I believe it can still be converted into the JAVA language.

The easiest approach, as far as I'm concerned, is to replace the quoted parts in the string with an empty string, then look for the matches. Hoping you're somewhat familiar with PHP, here's the idea.

```
$str = "Rhyme (Jack) and (Jill) went up the hill on \" (Peter's)\" request.";

preg_match_all(
    $pat = '~(?<=\().*?(?=\))~',
    // anything inside parentheses
    preg_replace('~([\'"]).*?\1~','',$str),
    // this replaces quoted strings with ''
    $matches
    // and assigns the result into this variable
);
print_r($matches[0]);
// $matches[0] returns the matches in preg_match_all

// [0] => Jack
// [1] => Jill
```

Comment: there could be single as well as double quotes, converting sounds like a work-around. I would ideally want a single regex to do the work.

Comment: @Scorpion There are numerous possibilities that can break a pattern. And because lookbehing and lookahead are not flexible enough to handle special characters like `*`, `?` and `+` it might be practically impossible to write a single regex to do what you want. But I'll be watching this question, I'm curious what others will come up with.